# I'm getting this error when I'm trying to archive my Xamarin android and iOS project

Tags: xamarin, build, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, mscorlib

Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "mscorlib". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.

I tried cleaning build, restoring project , updating NuGet packages but nothing is working

Comment: Can you build the app in release mode on a physical device?

Comment: For me below thing's worked:
Android : Set AndroidHttpClientHandlerType to Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler

iOS : In iOS i have deselected "Do not reference mscorlib.dll"

In Project properties settings.

Answer (score 0):

This things worked for me:

Android : Set AndroidHttpClientHandlerType to Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler

iOS : In iOS i have deselected "Do not reference mscorlib.dll"

In Project properties settings.